# anonymize-slide problem with creating object

Tags: python, subclass, openslide

I am trying to update [anonymize slide](https://github.com/j-hudecek/anonymize-slide/blob/master/anonymize-slide.py) (which deletes slide labels from scanned virtual slides) to work with Python3. It was written for `Python2.6` or 2.7. I don't think that python version compatibility is the problem here, though I could be wrong. Here's the code giving me the error:

```
class TiffFile(file):
    def __init__(self, path):
        file.__init__(self, path, 'r+b')
```

> `TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given`

I haven't used classes and methods too much, so these multiple **init** layers are confusing for me. Hopefully, the overall code will compile if this issue is fixed.

Comment: The problem isn't here - it is where you initialized a TiffFile.

Comment: I don't think TiffFile is initialized anywhere. The only other places where TiffFile   appears is in the form (for example):                                                                      def do_aperio_svs(filename):
    with TiffFile(filename) as fh:
        # Check for SVS file
        try: ...

Comment: What do you think `TiffFile(filename)` *is*, if not an initialization?  One of the places like that evidently has three parameters given, instead of one.

Comment: The error happens when the TiffFile class is created, in the lines of code above. I have not gotten to the point to try to initialize any specific TiffFile.